# Libmodbus library not found when trying to compile mbrtu

Tags: c, linux, libmodbus

I tried:

```
cd ~
git clone git://github.com/stephane/libmodbus
cd libmodbus
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-static
make
sudo make install
sudo cp ./src/.libs/libmodbus.a /usr/local/lib/
```

to download, compile and install the [libmodbus](https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus) library. Now I have a libmodbus.a file in /usr/local/lib/.

Now I want to install mbrtu:

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/gitaeuber/mbrtu
cd mbrtu
make
sudo make install
```

Strangely, after make I get the error:

```
In file included from mbrtu.c:22:
mbrtu.h:25:12: fatal error: modbus.h: No such file or directory
   25 | #include   <modbus.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:9: mbrtu] Error 1
```

I tried adding the library path /usr/local/lib/ to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but that did not help at all.

Can someone explain me how I can compile and install the libmodbus library correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a library that is not found by the linker but an include file which is not found by the compiler. Look at the make file `install` to see how include files are searched. It is likely a variable `INC` or `INCLUDE`.